# Errors in IntelliJ Kotlin Project

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, jvm

I created a Kotlin project but not working. (Using intellij idea Community EDITION 2021.3.1)
I have getting 3 errors:
[image: Invalid JVM Configuration]

And then The second one:
[image: BUG in Gradle Sync]

I am completely new to Kotlin. I am getting this eror. Please fix.
Also the thrid problem is that i cant run my kotlin kt file. Also ther is no Kotlin image showing.[image: Not able to run Kotlin]

Comment: Please post the errors as text. Ass for Kotlin, make sure you followed one of the guides available at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Hi. I cant understand the guidelines to follow in kotlinlang.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: What app you are trying to create? Try to download a sample one from github.